# Export HighChart as an image in excel file together with the other page contents

Tags: php, image, excel, graph, highcharts

Export HighChart as an image in excel file together with the other page contents like tables, text, etc. When I click the export button the whole Page content will be save as excel file via header but instead of exporting all page content to excel file it excludes the HighChart Graph. I think the solution is to export the graph as image in excel but I don't have any idea how to that. Is there anyone know how to do it or have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: seems like u are trying to save html page like xml file only with sending some headers? am i right?

Comment: Hi @StasGrin, sorry for very very late response to your question. This post has been ignored in many months after I posted it. You're idea is fine. is that possible? or converting HighchartGraph into image file and attached it on excel file via php? Thanks!

Comment: so just try out [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting)

Comment: Also, you can't just save HTML as XML and open it from Excel.

If you're using some extensions to generate Excel file, solution, i think, is in exporting graph into image and attach it to Excel file.

Comment: That is what I wanted to do, exporting the graph into image then attached it on excel together with the grid data but is it possible to be done using php?

Comment: posted an answer. too many text for comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Here is link on [highcharts documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting). Thats will help u to export image and store it.
2. a) [Documentation #1](http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Worksheet/PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing.html) 
   b) [Documentation #2](http://www.contao-docs.org/docs/PHPExcel/html/class_p_h_p_excel___worksheet___drawing.html) 
   That will help u with PHPExcel classs API.
3. And finally exapmle of image paste to a sheet, using PHPExcel class: [one](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/302680) or [two](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/271473);

Have more questions? See that links: [one](http://goo.gl/SEO6e), [two](http://goo.gl/PLl0i).
And official PHPExcel examples: [here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home).

Good luck!

Comment: This is great! I'll give you a feedback if I'm done testing this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: np :) just write to me with "@" - thats sends me a notification.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to send the svgtext and the csv text ti the server via ajax.
Then do the following:

public JsonResult ExportToImage(string base64, string graphdata)
        {
            try
            {

```
            var base64String = base64.Remove(0, 1);
            var rows = graphdata.Split('\n');

        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory , "Content\\Images\\");
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.xls")
                                 .Where(p => p.Extension == ".xls").ToArray();
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                try
                {
                    file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                    System.IO.File.Delete(file.FullName);
                }
                catch { }
            using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes)))
        {
            image.Save(path+"output.png", ImageFormat.Jpeg);  // Or Png
        }

            var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];

            for(var y=0; y<rows.Count();y++)
            {
                var row = rows[y];
                var columValues = row.Split(',');
                for (var x = 0; x < columValues.Count(); x++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[y+20, x+1] = columValues[x];
                }

            }


            xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(path + "output.png", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 0, 0, -1, -1);
            var fileName = string.Format("GraphDataExport{0}.xls", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss"));
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path + fileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true);
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            return Json(fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(e.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.InnerException + Environment.NewLine + e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

Now you can do a window.location to that file